# Working of Background Agents in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I had a plenty of doubts regarding background agents in windows phone mango. From a post i read about the background agent but i am still confused with the working of background agents. I tried with MSDN but feel difficult to grasp the abstract. Please any one suggest me a good blog or book to start learning the tech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer Peter Torr's bog for start learning background agent, In his blog he explained all information related with B.A with a simple example. If possible watch the keynote on Mix 2011 
by Peter.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/07/11/background-agents-part-1-of-3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This jump start has a good introduction to background tasks, and their limitations.  It also comes with source code:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Mango-Jump-Start/Mango-Jump-Start-06-Windows-Phone-Multi-tasking--Background-Tasks

I advise downloading and watching the entire series if you want a bigger picture about development in Mango.

Jesse Liberty's blog is also a good source for overviews and tutorials, he has a "Windows Phone Tutorials" link at the top.  Here is the background agent overview:

http://jesseliberty.com/2011/10/05/background-agents/

Though I note that he mentions the period task runs for around 25 seconds, somewhere on MSDN I saw 15 seconds.  Point being, you don't get long!

Comment: Thanks Adam for ur support. But it seems Peter Torr's Blog is much simpler. And he explained everything  in a spoon feeding manner.