# Updating live tiles for windows phone 8 periodically

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0, windows-phone-8

I need to update my application's tile periodically with the count the amount of inbox items. Anyone can give me a reference or relevant link to a example or tutorial? I get my data from a webservice. I went on google, and all the examples is on button click. I need one that does this automatically every few minutes/hours? This is for the windows phone 8 start screen of the phone.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want your code to run periodically even when the application isn't started, you have to use a background agent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835253/working-of-background-agents-in-wp7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the best tutorial I have seen for live tiles in wp8:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/live-tiles-in-windows-phone-8-part-1-tile-templates

Comment: yes that helped me to create the update, i just used a background agent to call the create tile function i made! thanks for the link

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this.  You can use Azure Mobile Services OR you can use a background process for your app to update the tile.  You can find information here :

http://thesociablegeek.com/windows-8/livetiles/modifying-live-tiles-in-a-background-process/

Daniel

Comment: hes asking about Windows Phone 8